# Need help on Uploading Multiple Image with compression

Tags: php, html, image, upload, compression

I have these code below to upload single image with compression. but right now I want to upload multiple image. Can someone help with with upload multiple image using the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Upload Compress and Check</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" />
           <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="submin" id="submit" />
     </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) { 
    $info = getimagesize($source_url); 
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url); 
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url); 
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url); 
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpg') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality); 

    return $destination_url; 
} 

if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != ""){

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $target_dir = "img/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $uploadOk = 1;

        if(file_exists($target_file)){  exist or not
            echo "<script>alert('sorry, file already exists.');</script>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }else if ($file_size > 500000) { 
            echo "<script>alert('sorry, your file is too large.');</script>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }else if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) { 
            echo "<script>alert('sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.');</script>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }else if($file_error > 0){ 
            echo "<script>alert('Your file is corrupted!');</script>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($uploadOk == 0){ 
            echo "<script>alert('sorry, your file was not uploaded!');</script>";
        }else{

            $rand = md5(sha1(rand(10000, 10000000))); 
            $url = $target_dir . $rand . '.jpg'; 
            $filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $url, 80); 

        }

    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('No image to upload!');</script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Thank you in advance.....

Comment: So you want us to take what you have for single file uploads and modify it for you so that it takes multiple files? What have you attempted to do to get multiple files to work?

Comment: @Jon Yes that what I want. if possible, please help. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a bit for the input "file" element:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="file[]" id="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Its ok, now you can use $_FILES["file"]["name"][0] to get the name of 1st file, or _FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][1] to get the tmp_name of 2nd file, and so on.

I hope you understand, i cannot explain more because i am using phone...

Comment: Ok. so need to add name="file[]"  and what about php code. how do i loop it?

Comment: You can use for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"];$i++){ }

Comment: for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"];$i++){ } or for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];$i++){ }  which one?